# has this predicate formula been translated correctly

Tags: logic, proof-verification, predicate-logic

I wanted to know if I translated the below sentence correctly to predicate logic

```
Only blue birds like singing and flying

∀ X • blue(X) ∧ bird(X) ⇒ likeSinging(X) ∧ likesFlying(X).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implication is running the wrong way. We want 
$$\forall x((\text{likesSinging}(x)\land\text{likesFlying}(x))\implies (\text{blue}(x)\land\text{bird}(x))).$$

Comment: thanks, can i shorten the blue(X) ∧ bird(X) to blueBird(X)?

Comment: One could argue about that. The problem is that bluebird is the name of  a particular species of bird, and there are other birds that are blue.